# What should you do when IT contact you during the night?

Tags: salary, work-environment, rights

What should you do when IT contact you during the night? I am getting calls from IT when I am not paid to work overtime and more than 40 hours a day. Is this normal? Also, I am not even getting paid the average salary for my position and nowhere on my contract does it say that I am expected to work overtime for some reason.

I am supposed to work as a full stack developer, but I am forced to do sysadmin, devops, db administration. Not sure what my salary should be, but it's should be higher than what it is currently.

Comment: What is your job? Who exactly are "IT"? From your company? A customer? Why are they contacting you? What do they want you to do?

Comment: What does your contract of employment say? Also, what is your goal? Do you want them to stop calling you at night? Do you want to get paid for keeping yourself available?

Comment: Have you gently mentioned your overwork and getting phone calls at night to your manager ? What does he say ? --- If possible, can you add a country tag to your question ?

Comment: Assume "40 hours a day" -> "40 hours a week"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Welcome back to The Workplace @Sayaman! I've placed your question on hold since it's unclear what you're actually asking. Whether this is normal depends on what your job exactly is, why you're being called and what your employer would like you to do. None of that info is in your post so we can't really provide any useful advice here. Can you [edit] your question to clarify what your role is, why you are being contacted, and what your manager's expectations are? You should also clarify what your goal is: do you *not* want to be contacted? Be paid (more) for your time? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

If you're not paid to work overtime and your contract doesn't state anything about you having to be available at all times, you can usually ignore work-related contacts (or answer with a brief "I'm not available") outside working hours.

If your management still insists that you have to answer such calls, consider looking for another job.